# How to express “unless”?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, expressions, subjonctif

Am I correct in thinking that in French you can express the idea of “unless” in the following three different ways? I wonder if you can use them interchangeably?

---

> 1. « Je vais prendre l'air. **À moins que** ce **soit** interdit, ça aussi ? »

{ à moins que + Present Subjunctive } ("ne" is omitted)

> 2. « Je vais prendre l'air. **À moins que** ce **ne soit** interdit, ça aussi ? »

{ à moins que + ne + Present Subjunctive }

> 3. « Je vais prendre l'air. **Sauf si** c'**est** interdit, ça aussi ? »

{ Sauf si + Present Indicative }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a good english speaker, but i'm French, so i can tell you my opinion ;)

All your suggests are right, but the first one is more straightforward.
Except as i would prefer:

"Je vais prendre l'air. À moins que **ça** soit interdit, ça aussi ?"

The second is a little bit complicated and not very used in everyday language.

On the contrary, the third is not very beautiful.
I dont know how to say that in english, be in french it's "familier, pauvre".

Comment: @user9167      I have a question: Can I use "ça" and "ce" almost interchangeably? Merci !

Comment: ouch, too difficult for me to explain that in english :) But no, they're not interchangeable

Comment: In example, you can say "ce soir", but not "ça soir"

Comment: @user9167      Oh, I see. I'd appreciate it if you could explain in French why you can use both "ça" and "ce" in this particular example.

Comment: Bon, on va essayer d'être clair ! "**ce**" est une abréviation de "**cet**" et "**ça**" est une abréviation de "**cela**". Avec "**ce**", on désigne un objet ou une situation, dont on a pas forcément la représentation en face de soi, par exemple "**ce** film", "**cette** chose", "**ce**  matin", etc... "**ça**", ou "**cela**" désigne uniquement un objet ou une situation directement désignable, exemple "**ça** m'ennuie", "C'est quoi **ça** ?"

Comment: @user9162 . Dans ce contexte, ce est un pronom démonstratif neutre: http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=1069607445;r=1;nat=;sol=0; . Il est équivalent à cela (ou ceci).  A différencier du ce=cet adjectif démonstratif.

Comment: @user9162 -- Pour les questions posées en anglais, les réponses en français sont acceptées, les bilingues peuvent aussi donner leur réponse dans les deux langues. Vous pouvez aussi compléter votre répons en ajoutant votre commentaire sur **ce, cela, çà...**

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina: That link is expired. (For this reason, you should never link to atilf.atilf.fr. For TLFi entries, use cnrtf.fr instead: http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/ce.)

Comment: @user9162 `Sauf si...` n'est pas du langage familier, c'est seulement un peu plus sec, percutant ;)

Comment: @user9162 Merci beaucoup ! I wonder if the following alternatives are more commonly used than Version 3? « Je vais prendre l'air. Si c'est pas interdit, ça aussi ? » ou « Je vais prendre l'air. Si ce n'est pas interdit, ça aussi ? »

Comment: Je crois que vous pouvez utiliser _informal_ et _weak/poor_ (préférablement le premier des deux à mon avis) dans ce genre de contexte...

Comment: You should not make giant comment threads like this to discuss something not related to the question! @pourrait puet-etre you ought to put up a question on the site for things like this, not start a comment discussion under an unrelated question! We have to keep the site organized somewhat, you know?

Comment: Also, I hate telling people this, but you really ought to at least google "ça vs ce" before asking here. That's not too hard to find an answer to.

Answer (score 2):

According to the existing answers and commentaries, the answer to that question highly depends on who answers. Given that I don't agree with all I've read, I publish my own point of view.

My answer is that all 3 forms are correct when speaking. If you write, I recommand you to use the second form, which is the most correct and formal in my opinion. Personally, I always use "ne" when speaking even if it's optional.

The use of "ce" is also perfectly correct ! It replaces "cela" (but the use of "cela" would be correct as well and a bit more formal). I won't suggest you to replace it by "ça", which makes the sentence more "popular" and is useless here.

Answer (score 1):

1 , 2 and 3 are correct.

*ce* is less frequent.

more frequent is: *à moins que cela (ne) soit interdit.*

you can use them interchangeably.

2 is more stylish.

3: *sauf si* is more frequent in everyday speaking.

Comment: Ha bon, tu préfères « Je vais prendre l'air. Sauf si c'est interdit, ça aussi ? » à «Je vais prendre l'air. À moins que ça soit interdit, ça aussi ?» dans le langage courant ?! Et non **ce** et **ça** ne sont pas interchangables dans n'importe quel contexte.

Comment: le "ne" n'est pas obligatoire. Il est très souvent omit à l'oral. A l'écrit, par contre, le style étant plus exigeant, il faut le mettre...

Comment: @Random - effectivement, ce n'est pas une phrase négative. j'ai répondu trop vite.

Answer (score 1):

All 1, 2 and 3 are all correct.

*Personal opinion*: In spoken language, I would use 1 or 2, indifferently (2 sounds better, but 1 is shorter). In written language, I think I will systematically use 2.

Concerning 2: after "*à moins que*", the "*ne*" (*ne explétif*) is usual. It is because "*à moins que*" indicates that the fact in the main sentence ("*Je vais prendre l'air*") will happen except if the condition in the subordinate (*ce soit interdit*) is satisfied. The "*ne*" just highlights this negative hypothesis.

> Examples:
>
> - J’irai à votre rencontre, à moins qu’il ne pleuve.
> - Ce travail sera terminé, à moins que quelque imprévu ne survienne.

*Source: [Université de montréal](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/observations/ne.htm)*

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

- **Most formal:** à moins que cela ne soit interdit.
- **Less Formal:** à moins que ce ne soit interdit.
- **Slang:** à moins que ça soit interdit.

Comment: Does the **de** in "prendre de l'air" mean **some**, with the entire phrase translating into "get **some** fresh air"? Merci.

Comment: At least in France, "prendre de l'air" is a nonsense in this context; a misinterpretation of the actual meaning of "prendre l'air".

Comment: I had this wrong, thank you jlliagre (I am not French).